# Angularjs Sharepoint Rest API to showing all columns

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, sharepoint

I have created a very basic controller to pull data from a SharePoint list, but it only pulls the base Title and created column. It doesn't pull any columns I have created, which are the ones I require. Is there a setting in SP itself to state it is available for the API?

I have used the code off this site:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-angularjs-with-single-a/

As shown here:

```js
var appVar = angular.module('listApp', []);  

appVar.controller("controller1", function($scope){    
    GetListItems($scope, "List1");    
});  

function GetListItems($scope, listName){    
    $.ajax({    
        url: "https://example.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+listName+"')/items",    
        method: "GET",    
        async: false,    
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },    
        success: function(data){    
            $scope.items = data.d.results;    
        },    
        error: function(sender,args){    
            console.log(args.get_message());    
        }    
    });    
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="listApp">    
    <div id="App1" ng-controller="controller1">    
        <h1>First List Items</h1>    
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">    
            <p>{{item.Title}}</p>    
        </div>    
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SP.ListItemCollection` resource endpoint

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items
```

returns all the field values for a list items with some limitation for User/Lookup fields (for performance reasons):

> In case of User/Lookup fields only lookup ids will be retrieved
>   by default.

In your example only `SP.ListItem.Title` property is printed, if you want to display all the returned list item values it could be accomplished like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">    
     <p>{{item.Title}}</p>
     <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
          {{ value }} 
     </p>    
</div>
```

Some another suggestions:

- Prefer [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) over `jQuery.ajax()` in Angular apps

**Example**

```
<div ng-app="spApp" ng-controller="TasksController" >
        <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="t in tasks">
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in t" ng-if="!value.hasOwnProperty('__deferred') && !value.hasOwnProperty('__metadata')">
                   {{ value }}
             </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('spApp',[])

.controller('TasksController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.tasks = [];

    $scope.getListItems = function(listTitle) {
        return $http({
               method : 'GET',
               url : _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items", 
               headers: { 'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        });
      }

     $scope.getListItems("Tasks")
           .success(function(data, status) {
               $scope.tasks = data.d.results;
           })
           .error(function(data, status) {
               console.log("An error occured");
     });
});
```

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks. My next question was to be how to achieve this other then ajax, so thanks again for the great value.

I have seen some other examples where people are adding Select tags on the end the urls, would this only be to limit the data returned as opposed to tell it what data to show with a k,d reference?

Comment: That's right, `select` query option is used to specify what properties should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just to shed some light further on this, I have noticed that the original pull was in fact bringing all my columns, but they were shown as Static names, not the Display name, so I was unable to first decipher them when showing the whole scope.

With this, I am able to view via the ng-repeat using the internal reference.